# Angular SSR type runtime error: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I am not able to run SSR server due to the following errors, I've attached the main.js file and the error log

Steps I've followed to produce main build

```
npm run build:ssr
```

error when running the SSR server were

```
/home/suhayb/repos/hisas/web-app/dist/web-app-server/main.js:4680
dayjs_1.default.extend(relativeTime_1.default);
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

So it seems dayjs is not supporting SSR.In Server side you cannot access DOM, window, localstorage...
Solution: use dayjs specific methods with conditions if it is browser only.
Example:

```
import { PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';
...
export class MyComponent {
...
    testBrowser: boolean;
    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) platformId: string) {
            this.testBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
            if (this.testBrowser) {
                //this is only executed on the browser

            }
    }
...
```